# Installing Windows 7 on notebook with Ubuntu installed

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, dell-inspiron

Does it possible install Windows 7 on Dell Inspiron 3543 Pentium 3805U? From Dell support page its not clear does it offer drivers for Win 7 or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Dell do provide drivers for Windows 7 for this model.

You can find the Windows 7 drivers here:

- [32-bit](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3543-laptop/drivers/advanced?os=w732)
- [64-bit](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3543-laptop/drivers/advanced?os=w764)